# What is the latest version of SQL Server native client that is compatible with Sql Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, native-client

Title says it all, what is the most recent version of Sql Server native client that is compatible with Sql Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/installing-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) is the latest and is backward compatible with 2008 and 2008R2 (as of July 9 2019, both windows and sql server 2008 and 2008r2 are fully unsupported).

[BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) warns you :

> The **SQL Server Native Client (SQLNCLI)** **remains deprecated** and it is **not recommended to use it for new development work**. Instead, use the new Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL) which will be updated with the most recent server features.

Comment: The fun thing is, after i asked this question, i found out that 11.0 doesnt support windows xp, and unfortunately we have test equipment we have not upgraded yet, Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @KySoto Your test equipment is running XP? Is production running XP too? Otherwise how much faith do you put in your tests?

Comment: we have pieces of equipment that can ONLY run on xp, it cant get on the internet, but obviously if something sneaks in, that computer would be vulnerable to it. on some of the applications running, it was homebrew code that a former engineer wrote, but bailed out on us. it takes a lotta time to replace.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2008 R2 is out of support, but AFAIK every existing SQL Server client library, including all SNAC and ODBC drivers should work fine with that version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, sadly we just dont have the cash to update to a newer version of sql server (im pushing!)

Answer (score 1):

I believe, there is no version beyond `SQL Server native client 11.0` which you can use for SQL Server 2008

Comment: Didnt realize you could connect to sql server 2018 with native client 11.0, neat bit of trivia.

Comment: @KySoto, sorry for the typo mistake, corrected!